# cv2.VideoWriter() returns strange video

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am using this function (inside a class) to save an array of images into a video. Despite the program running with no errors, the video I got, in the end, is not what was expected. It has a stripy effect even though when I print the images individually everything is ok.

```
def saveVideo(self):
        import cv2
        out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), self.fps, (160, 122), 0)
        for i in range(0, len(self.images)):
            out.write(self.images[i])
        out.release()
```

[image: The video I get]

Update: What happens is that the image in the video looks like the original image stretched, flipped, and with the black bars in the middle. There must be a problem with the video shape but I cannot manage to solve it.

Comment: Can you print self.images[i].shape?

Comment: @Micka it is (122, 160)

Comment: If I switch the 160 with the 122 in the VideoWriter then the video file is corrupted and I cannot open it.

Comment: not enough code to reproduce. please review [mre].

Comment: How many channels does your image have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried casting the images to uint8? Try:

`np.uint8(self.images[i])`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say try

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

instead of

```
cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
```

so like this

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", fourcc, self.fps, (160, 122), 0)
```

Comment: It didn't work :/

Comment: Damn. How are you calling self.fps? Is fps in function important to the project? You could try calling it with integers in cv2.VideoWriter(). Like: out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", fourcc, 60.0, (160, 122), 0)

Comment: tried that and did not work either. I really don't understand why

Comment: I'm out of options than :( Unless you comment the whole code haha

Comment: I can't share the whole code but I realized I have the same problem if I use random data: 

import cv2
data = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=[1000, 122, 160])
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 8, (160, 122), 0)
for i in range(0, len(data)):
        out.write(data[i])
out.release()